# Reference request for Evacuation Planning

Tags: reference-request, literature-research, journals

I have been assigned to make a literature review on evacuation planning. Could you please suggest some papers that I can use for the review?

Comment: Hi and welcome, Stefani, can you give a little bit more background? Exact and/or heuristic approaches, what papers do you already have, which keywords did you search for, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A buzzword that comes to my mind are *Flows over time* and especially *Earliest Arrival Flows*. Martin Skutella and students of his have worked out a bit of theory for that, see e.g.
[An introduction to Network Flows over time](ftp://ftp.math.tu-berlin.de/pub/Preprints/combi/Report-022-2008.pdf), [Earliest Arrival Flows with multiple sources](ftp://ftp.math.tu-berlin.de/pub/Preprints/combi/Report-035-2008.pdf), [Earliest Arrival Flows with multiple sinks](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~skutella/ISCO10-final.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

In reverse chronological order, here are some papers which use OR (or OR-related) techniques to solve problems in evacuation planning:

[Goerigk, Marc et al. "Ranking robustness and its application to evacuation planning." *European Journal of Operational Research* 264.3 (2018): 837-846.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2016.05.037)

[Swamy, Rahul et al. "Hurricane evacuation planning using public transportation." *Socio-Economic Planning Sciences* 59 (2017): 43-55.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.seps.2016.10.009)

[Pillac, Victor et al. "A conflict-based path-generation heuristic for evacuation planning." *Transportation Research Part B* 83 (2016): 136-150.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.trb.2015.09.008)

[Saadatseresht, Mohammad et al. "Evacuation planning using multiobjective evolutionary optimization approach." *European Journal of Operational Research* 198.1 (2009): 305-314.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2008.07.032)

[Sherali, Hanif et al. "A location-allocation model and algorithm for evacuation planning under hurricane/flood conditions." *Transportation Research Part B* 25.6 (1991): 439-452.](https://doi.org/10.1016/0191-2615(91)90037-J)

You can find many related articles through the literature review sections of these papers. Also, you may find the following reviews helpful.

[Galindo, Gina and Rajan Batta. "Review of recent developments in OR/MS research in disaster operations management." *European Journal of Operational Research* 230.2 (2013): 201-211.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2013.01.039)

[Altay, Nezih and Walter Green. "OR/MS research in disaster operations management." *European Journal of Operational Research* 175.1 (2006): 475-493.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2005.05.016)

Answer (score 3):

[Goerigk *et al*. (2014)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1366554514001471) may be a good start to your literature search. It uses mixed-integer programming to propose a genetic algorithm that can be used for urban evacuation planning. Examples of scenarios are provided at the end.

A bonus of this paper is that it already contains an extensive literature review in section 1.2.

---

<sub>Reference</sub>

<sub>[1] Goerigk, M., Deghdak, K., Heßler, P. (2014). A comprehensive evacuation planning model and genetic solution algorithm. *Transportation Research Part E: Logistics and Transportation Review.* 71:82-97.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Excluding papers listed in other answers...

**Surveys:**
Great starting points would be surveys on general evacuation and disaster operations management such as [Hamacher & Tjandra (2002)](https://kluedo.ub.uni-kl.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/1477/file/bericht24.pdf) and [Dhamala (2014)](http://dx.doi.org/10.3934/jimo.2015.11.265) for time-expanded network flow models. [Wright (2006)](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/10.1287/inte.1060.0253) gives a homeland security-themed survey.

**General Evacuation:**
Multiobjective evolutionary algorithm with GIS-integration: [Saadatsersht et al. (2019)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037722170800670X).

**Noncombatant Evacuation:**
Discrete Event Simulation (DES):  [Kuchell (2013)](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a618492.pdf); [Scheer (2011)](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a546629.pdf); [Olsen (2011)](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a546629.pdf), [Sumner and Zahn (1996)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/873392).

---

<sub>References (alphabetical order by last name of first author)</sub>

<sub>[1] T.N. Dhamala. 2014. A survey of models and algorithms for discrete evacuation planning network problems. *Journal of Industrial and Management Optimization*, 11(1):265–289.</sub>

<sub>[2] H.W. Hamacher and S.A. Tjandra. 2002. Mathematical modelling of evacuation problems: a state of the art. In M. Schrekenberg and S.D. Sharma, editors, *Pedestrian and Evacuation Dynamics*, pages 227–266. Springer, Berlin, Germany.</sub>

<sub>[3] D. Kuchell. 2013. Analyzing noncombatant evacuation operations using discrete event simulation, *Proceedings of the 2013 Winter Simulation Conference*, pages 2751–2761. R. Pasupathy, S.H. Kim, A. Tolk, R. Hill, and M.E. Kuhl, eds.</sub>

<sub>[4] C.M. Olsen. 2011. *Simulation study of evacuation control center operations analysis*, Master’s thesis, Air Force Institute of Technology.</sub>

<sub>[5] M. Saadatseresht, A. Mansourian, and M. Taleai. 2009. Evacuation planning  using multiobjective evolutionary optimization approach, *European Journal of Operational Research*, 198(1):305–314.</sub>

<sub>[6] M.A. Scheer. 2011. *Noncombatant evacuation operations in EUCOM*,  Master’s thesis, Air Force Institute of Technology.</sub>

<sub>[7] J.E. Sumner and E.A. Zahn. 1996.  A simulation of the evacuation of American citizens with an object-oriented animated model. *Proceedings of the 1996  Winter Simulation Conference*, pages 967–974. J.M Charnes, D.J.Morrice, D.T. Brunner, and J.J. Swain, eds.</sub>

<sub>[8] P.D. Wright, M.J. Liberatore, and R.L. Nydick. 2006. A Survey of Operations Research Models and Applications in Homeland Security. *INFORMS Journal on Applied Analytics*, 36(6):514–529.</sub>